# Jquery - adding functional draggable  code messes up program

Tags: jquery

Sorry, but I can only show this problem on a live sandbox site. if you go to [prupt.com](http://prupt.com), after about 8-10 seconds a drop down menu will appear in the middle of the screen. If you click "confirm" next to the dropdown menu, the background image will change and the boxes will disappear and reappear later on the next page.

All that works fine.

However, when I add this code below to make the boxes on the second page draggable and droppable, and then visit the site again, once I click "Confirm" on the first page, it just reloads the same first page without changing the background image etc.

This code below, in itself, is functional, as I tested it on this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/gq6En/65/

So can anyone explain why, if I add this code, it alters the functionality once you click the confirm button on the first page?

```
$(function(){
    $("#cloud1, #cloud2, #cloud3, #cloud4").draggable();
    $("#chair1, #chair2, #chair3, #chair4").droppable({
        accept: "#cloud1, #cloud2, #cloud3, #cloud4",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this)
                .addClass ("ui-state-highlight")
                .find ("p")
                .html("dropped");
            $("#topnav").css({'background':'pink'});
         }

      });
});
```

**Update,** when I put the code in this document ready (as suggested by @kwicher) and try again, the process to change to the second page starts, but then it reverts back to the first page.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {   
$("#cloud1, #cloud2, #cloud3, #cloud4").draggable();
        $("#chair1, #chair2, #chair3, #chair4").droppable({
            accept: "#cloud1, #cloud2, #cloud3, #cloud4",
            activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this)
                    .addClass ("ui-state-highlight")
                    .find ("p")
                    .html("dropped");
                $("#topnav").css({'background':'pink'});
             }

          });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute the code on $(document).ready

Comment: thanks, please see OP update. I put the function in a document ready and tried again, and it seems to start to work, but then it reverts back to the first page. Is there something wrong with my document ready?

Comment: I am not sure what is going wrong.If you make a minimal failing webpage with all sources it will be easier to debug

Comment: All the code`s in now. The confirm button class is "submit". Is there a way to write a function that only activates the draggables if the submit button has been clicked, and then delay it a little? Something like, if .submit = clicked, then $document ready?

Comment: I cannot see reference to jQuery UI source in your webpage

Comment: do I need a reference to jQuery UI? Why? Oh, o.k., I need it for the drag and drop. Thanks, I`ll add it, but that can`t be the reason why the page isn`t switching, is it?

Comment: Hey, I think that was the problem. You`re a genius! thank you.

Comment: well, it actually only works in part. On the second page, all the boxes on the right are supposed to be dropable inside the four boxes in the white box, but only one of them is droppable.  If you have an idea why this is so, please let me know. Cheers